# What is the meaning of "AdvertisingMillis" when advertising bluetooth data in Android L?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

As described in the API reference in Android L: https://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html

In android.bluetooth.le package, there is a class: AdvertiseSettings, and there are three advertise mode regarding on power:

1. ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED
2. ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY
3. ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER

I tried the different modes and want to see the detailed difference:

```
 advSetting = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                        .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                        .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TYPE_SCANNABLE)
                        .build();
```

And start the advertising using:

```
 bleAdv.startAdvertising(advSetting, advertisementData, advertiseCallback);
```

From the logcat, some logs (provided in the Android L SDK) regarding on the advertising will be available:

Low Latency:

```
 08-19 18:30:09.107    2507-2587/? D/GattServiceStateMachine﹕ enabling advertising:     5minAdvertisingMills 1600
```

Low Power:

```
08-19 18:44:59.333    2507-2587/? D/GattServiceStateMachine﹕ enabling advertising: 5minAdvertisingMills 160
```

Balanced:

```
08-19 18:41:36.284    2507-2587/? D/GattServiceStateMachine﹕ enabling advertising: 5minAdvertisingMills 400
```

From the logs above, it is clear that the AdvertisingMills are different in these three modes. However, I do not get what does the word "AdvertisingMills" means.

If it means the frequency that Android advertises the bluetooth data, then in Low Power mode, the data will be advertised every 160 ms, as comparison in Low Latency mode, data will be advertised every 1600ms. And if this is true, will Low Power mode cost more power than the Low Latency mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this: 
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=605 ?

It seems like this a bug in Android L.

Comment: Thanks Jones, I just saw the issue today. Yeah it should be a bug in the current Android L SDK.

Answer (score 0):

And now unfortunately Google set ALL advertising modes to the slooooow 1 second rate. Not quite a fix IMHO. It will take an iOS APP in the background up to 55sec to hear an Android 5 in Peripheral Mode. Not really "Low Power".
But yes it has been "fixed" as in fixing all three to the same value.